# Java: Catching lambda exceptions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Not able to wrap stream object in a `try/catch block`.

I tried like this:

```
reponseNodes.stream().parallel().collect(Collectors.toMap(responseNode -> responseNode.getLabel(), responseNode -> processImage(responseNode)));
```

Eclipse started complaining  underlining `processImage(responseNode)` and suggested that it needs to `Surround with try/catch`.

Then I updated to:

```
return reponseNodes.stream().parallel().collect(Collectors.toMap(responseNode -> responseNode.getLabel(), responseNode -> try { processImage(responseNode) } catch (Exception e) { throw new UncheckedException(e); }));
```

Updated code also did not work.

Comment: Could you type out the exact warning/error Eclipse is giving you?

Comment: Eclipse warning `Surround with try/catch` underlining `processImage(responseNode)`.

Answer (score 5):

Because the lambda is no longer a single statement, each statement (including `processImage(responseNode)` must be followed by a `;`. For the same reason, the lambda also requires an explicit return statement (`return processImage(responseNode)`), and must be wrapped in `{}`.

Thus:

```
return reponseNodes.stream().parallel()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(responseNode -> responseNode.getLabel(), responseNode -> {
            try {
                return processImage(responseNode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new UncheckedException(e);
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to handle checked exceptions in lambadas, only option I came up with is just move the logic to another method which can handle it with *try-catch*.

*For example*,

```
List<FileReader> fr = Arrays.asList("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt").stream()
            .map(a -> createFileReader(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
//....
private static FileReader createFileReader(String file) {
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fr;
}
```

Comment: It's probably for the best.  This is more readable.

Comment: >lambadas best typo ever